# Call an app from a bash script

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have an app on my Ubuntu machine installed in `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp`. When I try using `myfn` in my bash script `mybashscript.sh` it gives an error saying that the `myfn` command is not found, but if I call `myfn` from a normal terminal window it works fine since it's found in the `~/.bashrc` file. How I can call `myfn` from my bash script `mybashscript.sh`?

Here is `mybashscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

alias brc='source ~/.bashrc'

source /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
#exec bash
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
echo $PATH
echo "******************pathhhhhhhh************"
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp
```

This is the output when I run `./mybashscript.sh`:

```
bash: /bin/realbin/myapp: No such file or directory
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
******************pathhhhhhhh************
/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: 3: /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: /bin/realbin/myapp: not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: Please avoid crossposting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542209/call-a-function-from-a-bash-script-ubuntu

Comment: The actual error appears the program doesn't exist `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp: /bin/realbin/myapp`

Answer (score 1):

To make the function visible to your script you need to "source" the file into your script with:

```
source /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myfn
```

or:

```
. /usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myfn
```

This will include all the defined functions, variables and constants within the file into your script.

Comment: Is there a way to include all what is in the PATH environment variable found in ~/.bashrc?

Comment: That sounds like a different question: ***"How do I search a file for PATH commands?"***

Comment: I've updated the question with my script and output, could you please check?

Comment: You never posted the contents of `/usr/local/MYPROGRAM/bin/myapp` which you are both trying to include as a source file now and call as a program. Which is it a program to run our a source file to include?

Comment: The myapp is called mrc2tif found here https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/doc/man/mrc2tif.html  which is part of a program called IMOD